# android studio - json to settext

Tags: android, json

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "database ", "data pass", "database name");
$userID = $_POST["userID"];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userID like '$userID';");
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array("userPoint" => $row[4]));
}

echo json_encode(array("response" => $response));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm trying to use this php to send userID data to my database and receive the point of the user and set the data to settext in android studio.

I used two class to obtain data from my database

```
public class GameRequest extends StringRequest {
    final static private String URL = "http://smg6135.cafe24.com/ogi.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;

public GameRequest(String userID, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, URL, listener, null);
    parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("userID", userID);
}

@Override 
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return parameters;
}
}
```

to send request to my php and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String userid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView idtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userID);
    final TextView point = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    userid = intent.getStringExtra("userID");
    idtext.setText(userid);
    Response.Listener<String> responseLister = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String result = jsonObject.getString("userPoint");
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

                point.setText(arr.toString());


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    GameRequest gameRequest = new GameRequest(userid, responseLister);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(gameRequest);
}
}
```

to receive the data in Json array and display it by textview. Somehow it doesn't work... can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please be more specific about what doesn't work.

Comment: The php file works, I have tested with Jsonlint. But I'm having trouble to receive json data from php and showing it on android studio through settext. I don't know what is wrong with this java class files.

Comment: {
 "response": [{
  "userPoint": "0"
 }]
} this is what I would get when I put "smg6135" in the userID part in php

Comment: @SongMingon I have check answer if works then accept it .

Comment: can you please share the format of json response?

Comment: try gson library

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving response in **Array** Object so use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` as follows -

```
Response.Listener<String> responseLister = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
               JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
               for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   String result = jsonobject.getString("userPoint");
                   point.setText(result);
               }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
    };
```

I hope its work for you. Thanks